# Angularjs cant send data from input to nodejs server, POST not found 404

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Here are mistakes shown in console, i can't understand why http adress in is not found

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/message 404 (Not Found)                angular.min.js
XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost:3000/api/message".       angular.min.js
Error "Cannot POST /api/message\n"                                    controllers.js
```

my controllerjs:

```
testControllers.controller('SecCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
   function SecCtrl($scope, $http) {       
      $scope.message = '';
      $scope.saveInput = function() {              
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/message',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            data: JSON.stringify({message: $scope.message})      
        }).

        success(function(response) {
            console.log("Success " + JSON.stringify(response));
        }).

        error(function(response) {
            console.log("Error " + JSON.stringify(response));
        });
     };
}]);
```

server.js code, and after i send input data to server i try to save it into mongodb using mongoose:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var Message = mongoose.model('Message', {
    message: String
});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', function(err) {
    if(!err) {
        console.log('connected to mongo');
    }
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json({type: 'application/vnd.api+json'}));

app.use(function(res,req,next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type,   Authorization");

    next();
})

app.get('api/message', function(req,res) {
    Message.find(function(err,message) {
        if(err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            res.json(message);
        }
    })
})

app.post('api/message', function(req,res) {
    var message = new Message(req.body);
    message.save();

    res.status(200);
})

app.get('/', function(req,res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
})

app.listen(3000);
console.log('listening on port 3000');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be with absolute path `/api/message`:

```
app.post('/api/message', function(req,res) {
    var message = new Message(req.body);
    message.save();

    res.status(200);
});
```

Look at here http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#path-examples

Comment: i tried to write same path in controller, but it causes same mistakes

Comment: they are the same, i posted them at the beginnig of topic